# recursive function for compare two tuples and return one tuple with no repetitions

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, tuples

I've tried everything, but I can't make this function work at all. At least not the way I want.

```
def uniao(x, y):
 a = list(x)
 b = list(y)
 i = len(a)-1
 j = len(b)-1
  if a == b:
   return tuple(a) + tuple(b)
  else:

   if b[j] != a[i]:
    a.append(b[j])

    return uniao(a, b)
   else:
    return tuple(a)


print(uniao((1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5)))
```

This is where I approached the result, but it should be '12345'.

Comment: What kind of error or incorrect result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Does this rewrite of your function do what you want:

```
def uniao(x, y):
    if not y:
        return x

    head, *tail = y

    if head not in x:
        x += (head,)

    return uniao(x, tail)

print(uniao((1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5)))
```

Or are there more rules to this puzzle?